# JSON array is not being created from a stream

Tags: java, json

Basically, I'm sending a request to a server, and its reponse is `"{"Result":"OK"}"`, which I can retrieve, however when  I try and use the repsonse in my processing method:

```
public void ProcessData(java.lang.String stream) 
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray; 
        try
        {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(stream);
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String itemText = jsonObject.getString("text");
            Response = itemText;
        }
        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

if stream is  `"{"Result":"OK"}"`   it fails on this line

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(stream);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to create an array from an "object" (map).

Comment: (I'm guessing that if you looked at the exception message it would have told you this.)

Comment: Well because i'm returning JSON arrays sometimes as well I overlooked it as I'm new to java/ android

Comment: ALWAYS look at the exception message, when debugging Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing wrong your trying to parse `JsonObject` to `JsonArray`  try like

```
try {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(Respones);         
        String userid = jobj.getString("Result");               
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not a json array its a json object (starts with `{`)..

```
jsonobject = new JSONObject(stream);
```

Comment: Gee, where do you find objectys?

Answer (score 1):

This `jsonStr` is a `JsonObject` format:

```
{name:value}
```

not a `jSONArray` format:

```
[{name:value}]
```

you must use:

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(stream)
```

couldn't use new `JSonArray(stream);`

Answer (score 0):

There's no `JSONArray` there, just a `JSONObject`

```
jsonArray = new JSONObject(stream);
```